# How to style the scrollbar inside a ion-modal in Ionic 6?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, modal-dialog, scrollbar

ion-modal has a default scrollbar that will appear if the content overflows. I want to style that scrollbar.

I am able to style scrollbars in the app with ::-webkit-scrollbar, ::-webkit-scrollbar-track and ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb but it doesn't seem to work inside a modal. I've tried applying these elements to several components inside the modal like ion-content::-webkit-scrollbar but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the general approach you can take to style a scroll bar inside an ion-modal in Ionic 6.

1. Wrap your ion-modal content inside

> ion-content

tag like given below

```
<ion-content>
    //modal content goes here
</ion-content>
```

2. Then in global css file add below css for scrollbar

   ```
    ion-content {
        --offset-bottom: auto !important;
        --overflow: auto;
        background: var(--ion-toolbar-background, var(--ion-background-color, 
                     #000000)) !important;
        overflow: auto;

    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 5px;
        height: 5px;
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
        background: #35d703;
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: rgb(75, 75, 75);
    }

     &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
         background: #94173a
     }

     .inner-scroll {
         scrollbar-width: thin;
     }
   }
   ```

Your scroll will look like below in ion-modal

[image]

Comment: Should be --overflow: hidden; otherwise it doesn't work on Opera and maybe some other browsers.